# Error ORA-00942 running DBMS_COMPARISON.CONVERGE subprogram

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00942

I get the ORA-00942 - table or view does not exist - error when I run a stored procedure which use the DBMS_COMPARISON package to sync two tables over two different schemas.

This is roughly what I have:

```
remote table        local comparison     local table    
DB1.PRODUCTS        DB2.PRODUCTS_CMP     DB2.PRODUCTS
```

This is the local DB2 procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SYNC_SINGLE AS
          L_SCAN_INFO         SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARISON_TYPE;
          L_RESULT            BOOLEAN;   
          L_COMPNAME          VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
          L_COMPNAME:='PRODUCT_CMP';
          
          SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON.PURGE_COMPARISON(
                   COMPARISON_NAME => L_COMPNAME
          );

          L_RESULT := 
                    SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE (
                    COMPARISON_NAME => L_COMPNAME,
                    SCAN_INFO       => L_SCAN_INFO,
                    PERFORM_ROW_DIF => TRUE
          );

          FOR ROW_ID IN (
                    SELECT    SCAN_ID
                    FROM      USER_COMPARISON_SCAN_SUMMARY
                    WHERE     COMPARISON_NAME = L_COMPNAME
                              AND STATUS = 'BUCKET DIF'
          )
          LOOP      
                    SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON.CONVERGE (
                              COMPARISON_NAME  => L_COMPNAME,
                              SCAN_ID          => ROW_ID.SCAN_ID,
                              SCAN_INFO        => L_SCAN_INFO,
                              CONVERGE_OPTIONS => SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON.CMP_CONVERGE_REMOTE_WINS, 
                              PERFORM_COMMIT   => FALSE
                    );
          END LOOP ROW_ID;

          SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON.PURGE_COMPARISON(
                   COMPARISON_NAME => L_COMPNAME
          );

END SYNC_SINGLE;
```

The procedure ends with these errors:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 734
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 5964
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 682
ORA-06512: a "DB2.SYNC_SINGLE", line 26
ORA-06512: a "DB2.SYNC_SINGLE", line 26
ORA-06512: a line 2
```

I guess there is a permission issue here but I can't figure out what it is. The user SYS have got all the permissions granted on the local table DB2.PRODUCTS.
Also, I have other tables on the same schemas that I sync in the same way and for those tables everything goes just fine. Looking at the tables SYS.COMPARISON$ and SYS.COMPARISON_COL$ everything seems to be configured correctly.

Can anyone help suggesting what I should check out?

Comment: Are table privileges granted directly to the procedure owner, or via a role?

Comment: All the privileges are granted directly to the user SYS

Comment: When you refer to a table as `DB2.PRODUCTS`, what exactly does that mean?  You say that you have a local and remote database but `DB2.PRODUCTS` would refer to a `PRODUCTS` table in the `DB2` schema of the local database and `DB1.PRODUCTS` would refer to a `PRODUCTS` table in the `DB1` schema of the local database.  If you have an object in a remote database, that would need to be reference via a database link (i.e. `PRODUCTS@db1`).  Did you create separate `PRODUCTS` tables in the `SYS` schema of both a local and a remote database?

Comment: I'm also failing to see where you run a `create_comparison`.

Comment: The two schemas (DB1 and DB2) are in two separate databases. DB1.PRODUCTS is in the remote one and there is a database link. The comparison was made with a separate procedure.

Comment: @MonkeyH - If you are creating the comparison in a separate procedure why are you purging the comparison at the beginning of the this procedure?  That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @JustinCave - The procedure doesn't handle exceptions, so the first purge is there to clean up eventual "dirty" data resulting from a previous failed execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what it was: **AUTHID CURRENT_USER** was missing in the procedure declaration.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SYNC_SINGLE AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
```